# I can't boot my Windows installer

Tags: boot, windows

I'm trying to install Windows 8 because I removed it accidentally.

What I've tried:

- extracted iso and added the boot flag within Ubuntu
- extracted iso using PowerISO within Windows 7 (other computer)
- change boot order

What happens when it starts:

- no video mode activated
- Loading linux 3.8.0-10-generic
- Loading initial randisk

Ubuntu 13.04 Beta 2

I've done this always and worked successfully, also I tried different iso's and same happens.

Comment: Are you in secure boot mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like Grub is not configured to see the Windows boot partition, and you're booting into GRUB rather than Windows Boot Manager.

The simplest (but more time-consuming) way to handle this is to completely wipe the system and install Windows 8 by itself.  Then install Ubuntu alongside.

The faster but more difficult/risky way, is to take your chances with reconfiguring Grub.  Here is [a good tutorial on Grub2](http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/grub-2.html) that may help you, and [here are some instructions](http://www.techsupportforum.com/357-how-to-configure-grub-bootloader-in-mint-linuxubuntu/) that might help you as well.  Unfortunately you can't follow them verbatim, but they may help you get it figured out.